# Is there a way to load different part of the pages at different time in php

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ajax

I'm using php and javascript and what i want to do is to load the different sections of a web page at different time such that first my header and side slider loads up and then my middle content. And also, when user scrolls down then only the images loads up.

Comment: Yes, you can do this with JavaScript quite easily, but don't.  Leave the loading up to the browser, unless you have a very specific reason to do so otherwise.

Comment: @Brad how it can be done

Comment: The page loads in the order of your source code. If you want your header to load first, put that at the top of your body. If you want your sidebar to load next, make that the next block of code below the header, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to asynchronously load contents to your page very easy.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

But you will not win performance on that, unless you have very big blocks of content you want to load in portions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is the purpose of PHP... nor does it work like that.

I wouldn't intentionally delay load time, so using jquery .load() just for the sake of a visual effect is bad practice. If you just want the visual effect of loading the parts at different times you can do the following:

1. In the head, add the following script. I would add it right after or before your style sheets.

```
var thehtml = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
thehtml.className = 'loading';

function hasClass(ele,cls) {
    return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
}

function removeClass(ele,cls) {
    if (hasClass(ele,cls)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
        ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
    }
}

window.onload = function() {removeClass(thehtml, "loading")}
```

1. Style the .loading class:

```
.loading #header,
.loading #sidebar {opacity: 0}

#header,
#sidebar {opacity: 1; transition: all 3s ease-in-out;}
```

This will cause the header and sidebar to fade in once the loading class is removed. If your middle content consists of all images, you can use a "lazy loader" like lazy karl. http://www.karlsteltenpohl.com/blog/,56,

In general I think all lazy load plugins are bad for performance as you have to rely on a scroll event, which means javascript runs a function every time the user scrolls the page.

Additionally if you want to have more control over the timing and order of "loading" you can use `setTimeout()` inside of the `window.load` function to have the elements load at different times.

If you choose this solution there will be alot more CSS involved and that will depend on your individual layout and how you've coded it.

Comment: When you have code within a numbered list in SO, you have to add eight spaces instead of the regular four, or multiples of considering the depth of list item.

Answer (score 0):

Sobhagya Mohanty you should remember three important things:

1) Asynchrony doesn't mean fastest performance but means not-blocking (your code execution will not be blocked by loading other resources).

2) Every piece of page loaded by Javascript will be invisible to all Search Engines, so since you are talking about a Web Page (and not a Web Application), you will hide Google (and others SE) important contents.

3) What j-man86 wrote is the best way to add effects to page sections without hiding them to Search Engines.

Best Regards,
Fabio Buda
http://www.en.netd.it